# Django accepts special characters on url

Tags: django, django-urls

Im trying to reach a path but not working as i want.
What i want is to go a specific section of the page, which i can reach using bootstrap with an address like: `<a href="#formt">` but as you may know, django turns *#* into *%23* and what i get in the Browser's url is `www.misite.com/chg-profil/%23formt` and with this address, i can´t reach my target.
**In my urls.py:**
`path('chg-profil/', Formt.as_view(),name='chg-profil'),`
**In my template.html:**
`<a class="nav-link" href="{%url 'chg-profil/#formt'%}">`

Answer (score 2):

The argument of the `url` template tag is the *name* of the url, not the url itself. Use:

`<a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'chg-profil' %}#formt">`

instead. This will replace the whole `{% url %}` tag with the url called  `chg-profil`, resulting in `chg-profil/#formt`.

Comment: My man : ) You answered correctly that is what  i wanted, although bootstrap is not taking me where i want i appreciate your answer, thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that there is an HTML element with `id` *exactly equal to* `formt` on the `chg-profil/` page?

Comment: Yes i'am! I'm using a Bootstrap4 Nav Tab that is not taking me anywhere. Never mind, i just fixed it... Needed to pass a script to activate de Jquery to show the right Tab.